# python sorting based on parallel arrays

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of objects and I'd like to sort them based on a parallel array.  So, as I operate over a list of data I construct a parallel array (where each entry in that list corresponds to an entry in the original list).  Then (let's say the parallel array is filled with numbers)

```
list_a = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 )
list_b = (4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 9, 0, 8 )
```

I want to sort the original list of objects based on the parallel arrays values so that the original list is sorting in ascending order by the numerical value in the other array.  Is there any way to do this built into python?

```
sort_a_by_b(list_a, list_b)
```

Expected result would be:

```
list_a_sorted_by_b = (8, 4, 1, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 9, 7 )
```

Comment: BTW, what you have there are tuples, not lists or arrays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> list_a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list_b = [4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 7, 3, 9, 0, 8]
>>> 
>>> import operator
>>>
>>> [k for k, v in sorted(zip(list_a, list_b), key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
[8, 4, 1, 6, 0, 2, 3, 5, 9, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the object list `objects` and the other list `sort_keys`. If you can compute `sort_keys[i]` from just the value of `objects[i]`, you don't even need to build `sort_keys`. You should just do this:

```
objects.sort(key=compute_sort_key_for_object)
```

where `compute_sort_key_for_object` is the function you would use to compute `sort_keys[i]` from `objects[i]`. It's faster and more readable.

If the processing to compute `sort_keys` is more complex, you'll want Rohit's answer:

```
import operator
[k for k, v in sorted(zip(objects, sort_keys), key=operator.itemgetter(1))]
```